# Move postgresql data store (port stops listening)

Tags: database, linux, postgresql, ubuntu, centos

I have moved my data store from default `/var/lib/pgsql/9.3/data` to new disk to improve performance. Everything goes well and server starts fine, but it stops accepting requests on 5432 port. I have done some research and so far I understand that it can be that under my linux distro (CentOS 9.5) instead of  `/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432` it is configured to use some other path. I have tried to change unix_socket_directories but with no success.
Any ideas how to solve this ?

**EDIT**

Here are the steps how I have changed the data folder

```
#In /etc/init.d/postgresql-9.3
PGDATA=/my_new_disc/pgdata/data
PGLOG=/my_new_disc/pgdata/data/pgstartup.log

# under root user
> mkdir /my_new_disc/pgdata/data
> chmod 775 /my_new_disc/pgdata/data
> chown postgres/my_new_disc/pgdata/data

# switch to postgres user 
> su postgres
> initdb /my_new_disc/pgdata/data
```

After this I was able to run service successfully and can see that Postgres is listening port 5432, but it was possible to connect only while being logged in as postgres user.

It was not working even from root user on the same machine when I try

```
psql -h localhost -U postgres postgres
```

It asks for password and says that was failed to connect.

**EDIT2**:

The other option I am thinking is to use symbolic links...Would it be better ?

Comment: Examine the server error log in the PostgreSQL data directory. Is there any error output there? Also: Did you stop PostgreSQL before moving the datadir?

Comment: Are you running with SELinux enabled?

Comment: @Craig there is no message in the log ... it is just not accepting any request on 5432 port and yes database was shut off at that moment.

Comment: @Tamerlane Good point there by Scott. What's the output of `getenforce` (run as a shell command)? Are there any SELinux denials in `dmesg`? Is PostgreSQL *really* running? `ps -f -u postgres`.

Comment: @ScottMarlowe I checked SELinux is disabled.

Comment: @CraigRinger Postgres was running ok as I was able to connect using psql on the same machine ... but it woks only if I am running psql under postgres user...it doesn't work from root

Comment: do you guys think that symbolic link would be better option ?

Comment: @Tamerlane **Exact text** of the error message you get?

Comment: @CraigRinger I have rolled back, let me try to set up everything and will get back with detailed message. But here is what I saw...on PgAdmin message was no listener on IP/port and on psql while running as root it says login/auth failed.

Comment: I end up using symbolic links. It works like a charm. Thanks for you help and time guys

Comment: This sounds like a problem with your pg_hba.conf file. Try real quick creating a local and host line set to accept all connections as trust and see if it starts working. Then start closing off things from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are being prompted for a password, it means that the database is listening, but that you need to configure your connection method.

The configuration file that you need to look at is at /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf (you need to be root to edit it).

You will see lines (after the comments) that look something like:

```
local   all             postgres                                peer
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
```

Lines that start with "local" refer to unix socket connections.
The next entry is which databases this applies to (usually "all").
Then comes the db user ids this applies to.
For a "host" line, you need to specify the IP range this applies to.

Your problem is related to that last entry.   "peer" means that you must be logged in as a unix user of the same name.  "trust" means that the database won't ask for a password.  And "md5" will prompt for a password.

So, if you want to connect to the database as the "postgres" user, you want lines that look like:

```
local    all     postgres     trust
host     all     postgres     127.0.0.1/32  trust
```

Then,  `psql -U postgres postgres` will not ask for a password.

A configuration line for the postgres user should come before a similar line for all users (the db will use the first rule that matches).

Be aware that by using "trust", anybody can log in to the database without providing a password.   You may wish to consider setting up a password in the database for the postgres user then reverting the pg_hba.conf file to using md5.